# Express the following mathematical statement in predicate logic.

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

Is this a correct expression of the mathematical statement, "Every positive real number has exactly two square roots.";

expression: ∀x∃a∃b((x>0) → (a!=b)∧(x=$a^2$)∧(x=$b^2$)).

Comment: This says  every positive number has at least two square roots.

Comment: Yeah but is the statement, "Every positive real number has exactly two square roots.", the same as the statement "Every positive real number has only two square roots."?

Comment: Sort of, it is a little hard to translate only. But your formal sentence does not say exactly, it says there are two but leaves open the possibility that there may be more.

Comment: I see, I just sense, that the term exactly also leaves open the possibility that there is more in any general way.  Let me try this;  Say I have 12 eggs in my fridge, and I need exactly 2 eggs for a recipe.  Say I'm internalizing a question, do I have exactly 2 eggs?  I look in my fridge, and I find I do have exactly 2 eggs from my 12 eggs.

Comment: You are taking an interpretation which is sufficiently non-standard that it would be almost certainly be considered wrong.

Comment: I suppose, I'm just confusing myself, with the term exactly, as I need exactly 2 eggs, I struggle with visualizing this generally, to me its like make sure you have at least 2 eggs, otherwise you would state, I need 2 and only 2 eggs.

Comment: Suppose that there are a dozen eggs in the fridge, and someone asks you how many eggs there are. You look, count,  and say to the person "there are exactly $2$ eggs in the fridge." I think you would be very widely viewed as having lied.

Comment: Haha, yes I would for that question!

Comment: Note that if the person asks "are there $2$ eggs in the fridge," in ordinary language it is not clear whether "yes" is correct if there are $12$. But "exactly" would strongly swing things to yes is not correct. However, the question is not about eggs. Mathematical English is a relative of ordinary English in which many of the ambiguities of ordinary language are stripped away by making precise conventions about the meaning of words.

Comment: Let me follow here, "How many square roots does a positive integer have?" (We know that the answer is 2.)  So I would respond, "A positive integer has exactly 2 square roots." or I would respond, "A positive integer has only 2 square roots."  These would have the same interpretation?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, there is some fuzziness about "has only." So, with some reservations, I would answer yes.

Comment: Is the fuzziness you speak of, the sense of the statement has only, as in it could be interpreted that a positive real number has only the property that it has 2 square roots?

Comment: "Has only the property" is very unclear. There is no sense in discussing the hypothetical "only" when we do not have a mathematical context. It could be interpreted as exactly, but "can only have $n$" could be interpreted as meaning "no more than $n$."

Comment: Ah your right, I feel ridiculously slow today.  I should say then, "There are exactly x of n."  is the same as "There are at least x of n and at most x of n?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  That discussion resolved quite a lot of problems for me!

Comment: You  are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The statement as written is true, but doesn't capture the word "exactly". Additionally, your quantification is a little odd: I'd have expected it to read $$(\forall x)(x>0 \to \exists a \exists b \dots)$$
because (while yours is true) it's a bit more work to check that yours really is true in the case that $x \leq 0$.

I'm going to use several different shapes of brackets to try to make this easier to read, but they're all just brackets.
To capture "exactly", you want $$(\forall x)\left[x > 0 \to \left[(\exists a)(\exists b) \{(a \not = b) \wedge (a^2 = x) \wedge (b^2 = x) \color{red} {\wedge (\forall c)} \color{red} {\left((c^2 = x) \to [c = a \vee (c=b)]  \right) }\} \right] \right]$$

Comment: Thank you for this example, also I have another question with an alternate construction from where you left off.  Would this expression also be valid? Would the iff only add trivial information in this general sense?            (∀x)[x>0→[(∃a)(∃b){(a≠b)∧($a^2$=x)∧($b^2$=x)∧(∀c)(($c^2$=x) iff [c=a∨(c=b)])}]]                                         I reason that the (∀c)(($c^2$=x) iff [c=a∨(c=b)]) is equivalent to (∀c)((($c^2$=x)→[c=a∨(c=b)])∧([c=a∨(c=b)]→($c^2$=x))).

Comment: Or the simpler $$
(\forall x)(x>0 \rightarrow (\exists a)(\exists b)(a \not= b \;\land\; (\forall c)(x = c^2 \;\leftrightarrow\; c = a \lor c = b)))
$$  Note how this uses a "there exist exactly 2" quantifier: $$
(\exists^{=2} w)(P(w)) \;\leftrightarrow\; (\exists y)(\exists z)(y \not= z\;\land\; (\forall w)(P(w) \;\leftrightarrow\; w = y \lor w = z))
$$ (I just invented the $\exists^{=2}$ notation here) which essentially is a "two-point generalization" of the 'there is a unique' quantifier, $$
(\exists!w)(P(w)) \;\leftrightarrow\; (\exists y)(\forall w)(P(w) \;\leftrightarrow\; w = y)
$$